# How can I set the drawableRight resource via code?

Tags: android, button, drawable

I am trying to set an image on the right side of my button after the button has been clicked. I want to do this via code.

I have seen how to change the background resource via code but I am not able to find any examples showing how to change the sides via code. Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by side change?, was your image on the left side of button before the button click?

Comment: It's on the right side and it's a red dot. I want to change it green on click. (It's a toggle button)

Comment: setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds

related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250923/how-to-change-a-buttons-icon-programmatically

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use the

```
public void setCompoundDrawables (Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, 
 Drawable bottom)
```

method with null for any that are not needed.

Comment: I was able to do it with this:     button_drill.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_button_green, 0);
 or should I use Drawables and turn my resource into a drawable?

Comment: Most probably you want to use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`. With the other method you would have to call `setBounds` on the Drawables before passing them as parameters, otherwise they will not be rendered correctly (won't be visible at all)

Answer (score 8):

Usually you can change using this

```
Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.facebook);
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, draw, null);
```

Be aware you can miss the button text.