# Android EditText.setError not working in not focusable

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, focusable

How can I display a text error with setError in an EditText not focusable? It's important that users don't modify this EditText, it'll be modified for the application. Maybe I have another option different than focusable=false?

Now, I have it:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Or don't use an EditText?  Why not a TextView?

Comment: Or set android:editable="false"?

Comment: With EditText (and removing focusable=false) I don't get the setError message.

Comment: And unfortunately editable=false don't work. With it I can show my error message but actually I can edit this field. I've also tried with inputType=none (the same but don't deprecated) and the result was the same.

Comment: Sorry, in my comment from Dec 16 at 17:31 I really meant TextView instead of EditText.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I think it's not possible to do... Because the first necessity is to block the text, doing it with focusable=false or with a TextView, and it also blocks the functionality setError.

An editText with focusable = false I can get a right drawable (the default red exclamation mark) but without text. For this reason I finally added the text with a Toast.

It's not completelly that I wanted, but it's the most similar.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use TextView and if you have an error somewhere then show image with drawableRight.
Here's the example of doingit programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7380789/3864698